# How to print 2 lines under a line from a text file?

Tags: python-3.x

Edit : I want to print 2 lines under the code entered by the user but it doesn't seem to work.

my text file looks like this :

```
86947367
banana
5

78364721
apple
3

35619833
orange
2

84716491
sweets
8

46389121
chicken
10
```

I have tried :

```
file = ('read_it.txt')
user = input('Enter code')

with open(file, 'r') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    for i, line in enumerate(lines):

        if line == user:
            print("{}\n{}".format(lines[i+1], lines[i+2]))
```

But i get an output of 2 blank lines.

Answer (score 0):

```
file = 'filename.txt'
user = input('Enter code')

with open(file, 'r') as f:
    lines = [line.strip() for line in f.readlines()]  # Strip \n and \t from text
    for i, line in enumerate(lines):  # enumerate will count and keep track of the lines
        if line == user:
            print("{}\n{}".format(lines[i+1], lines[i+2]))
```

Comment: the code makes sense but it just gives me an empty line.

Comment: @Jeff1231 Make sure of the obvious first (that your text file really does contains text), next I would try printing every line to make sure you're not missing something simple. The first and second line after a code may actually be blank lines. You could also try printing `line` after going into the if statement to further troubleshoot.

Edit your question with the code you are currently using for better assistance.

Comment: I tried printing lines after the if statement and it successfully printed everything in my text file , but nothing on 2 lines under it.

Comment: Okay, I think I figured this out. When reading from a text file a line is read as `'35619833\n'`, which includes the line break element within your string. Use the `.strip()` method to normalize your strings when reading from a text file. My code above has been updated.